# Quick tool which allows you to browse lists and view their IDs?

Tags: production, tools

I was wondering if there is a tool I can quickly install on a sharepoint production server to allow me to browse lists in a site, and display their names + id's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe overkill for you what you need, but if you haven't got it already, get SharePoint Manager. Allows you to view every object in a SharePoint Farm and view all it's properties.

http://spm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint Manager (as suggested by James) could be your first choice. If that is not allowed in production, PowerShell can help you.

Following command would give you what you need

$web = Get-SPWeb [URl of your web site]

$web.Lists | Select Title, ID